# How to set configuration in Flask-Security?

Tags: python, flask, flask-security

I want to set a value for `SECURITY_PASSWORD_SALT`. The [documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/configuration.html) gives a huge list on configuration items, but it does not explain how to set such an item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `app.config`, it works like a dictionary.

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECURITY_PASSWORD_SALT'] = 'foobar'
```

You should read [this](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/quickstart.html#sqlalchemy-application)